# Use of observer_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, c++17

What exactly is the point of the construct [`std::observer_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) in the library fundamentals technical specification V2?

It seems to me that all it does is wrap a bare `T*`, which seems like a superfluous step if it adds no dynamic memory safety.

In all of my code I use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) where I need to take explicit ownership of an object and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) where I can share ownership of an object.

This works very well and prevents accidental dereferencing of an already destroyed object.

`std::observer_ptr` makes no guarantee about the lifetime of the object observed, of course.

If it were to be constructed from a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` I would see a use in such a structure, but any code that is simply using `T*` is probably just going to keep doing so and if they plan on moving to anything it would be `std::shared_ptr` and/or `std::unique_ptr` (depending on use).

---

Given a simple example function:

```
template<typename T>
auto func(std::observer_ptr<T> ptr){}
```

Where it would be useful if it stopped smart pointers from destroying their stored object while they are being observed.

But if I want to observe a `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` I have to write:

```
auto main() -> int{
    auto uptr = std::make_unique<int>(5);
    auto sptr = std::make_shared<int>(6);
    func(uptr.get());
    func(sptr.get());
}
```

Which makes it no safer than:

```
template<typename T>
auto func(T *ptr){}
```

---

**So, what is the use of this new structure?**

**Is it just for self-documenting source?**

Comment: You can pass `std::begin({1,2,3})` to `func(T*)`, which may or may not be intended. OTOH, `func(observer_ptr<T>)` only accepts `make_observe(std::begin({1,2,3}))` and does not accept `std::begin({1,2,3})`.

Comment: I think I posted a question about just this kind of thing a few years ago (can't find it now).  For a resource manager I wanted something not quite a weak_ptr but not an actual shared_ptr either.  In the end I settled for unique_ptr handing out raw pointer instances.  But it wasn't all that clear what the caller was allowed to do with the raw pointer.  This clarifies things somewhat and I like it.

Comment: reading through the comments, it would be nice if the observer_ptr automatically becomes null when the shared_ptr owned resource got destroyed

Comment: @Avithohol It sounds like you want `weak_ptr`. The entire deal of `observer_ptr` is to have no effect on, or from, lifetime of the pointed-at object.

Comment: @underscore_d true that, but the name a bit misleading, don't you think. When i first heard, i thought its along the observer pattern, which exactly solvable by this scenario where observers sign up for subjects, and gets notificated (nulled in this case) upon their subjects destruction. My only problem with weak_ptr's that they need to be converted to shared_ptr if one wish to dereference them. Which can be expensive considering the thread safety features of shared_ptr.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf) makes it pretty clear that it's just for self-documentation:

> This paper proposes `observer_ptr`, a (not very) smart pointer type that takes no ownership
>   responsibility for its pointees, i.e., for the objects it observes. As such, it is intended as a near
>   drop-in replacement for raw pointer types, with the advantage that, as a vocabulary type, it
>   indicates its intended use without need for detailed analysis by code readers.

Comment: Considering that the first revision considered implicit conversion from other smart ptrs...  Is there a record of that being discarded?

Comment: @Yakk I don't see implicit conversions [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3514.pdf), unless I'm totally missing something.

Comment: The first draft had a question about it, or at least that is how I read it (interop with other smart pointers)

Comment: "4 Some open questions
1. At the moment, exempt_ptr knows of no other smart pointer. Should exempt_ptr innately
interoperate with any of the standard smart pointers? If so, with which one(s) and to
what degree? More generally, can WG21 articulate a smart pointer interoperability policy or
rationale in order to guide us in such decisions?"

Comment: Is there any meaningful difference with `std::reference_wrapper` except that `reference_wrapper` can't be null ?

Answer (score 37):

**When you need *shared access* but not *shared ownership*.**

The problem is that *raw pointers* are still very useful and have perfectly respectable use-case scenarios.

When a *raw pointer* is managed by a *smart pointer* its cleanup is guaranteed and so, within the lifespan of the *smart pointer*, it makes sense to access the actual data through the *raw pointer* that the *smart pointer* is managing.

So when we create functions, that would normally take a raw pointer, a good way of promising that the function will not delete that pointer is to use a strongly typed class like `std::observer_ptr`.

When passing a managed *raw pointer* as an argument to a `std::observer_ptr` function parameter, we know that the function is not going to `delete` it.

It is a way for a function to say "give me your pointer, I will not meddle with its allocation, I will just use it to observe".

Incidentally I'm not keen on the name `std::observer_ptr` because that implies you can look but not touch. But that is not really true. I would have gone with something more like `access_ptr`.

**Additional note:**

This is a different use-case from a `std::shared_ptr`. The `std::shared_ptr` is about sharing *ownership* and it should **only** be used when you can not determine which *owning object* will go out of scope first.

The `std::observer_ptr`, on the other hand, is for when you want to share *access* but not *ownership*.

It is not really appropriate to use `std::shared_ptr` simply to share *access* because that could be very inefficient.

So, whether you are managing your *target pointer* using a `std::unique_ptr` or a `std::shared_ptr` there is still a use-case for *raw-pointers* and hence the rational for a `std::observer_ptr`.

Comment: Isn't `std:reference_wrapper` just fine for shared access ?

Comment: @aberaud Could be. But the question was about `std::observer_ptr` so...

Comment: The main difference with reference_wrapper is that it can be nullptr

Comment: From what I gather, this is just like  a "weak pointer" from other lanugages. Is there a reason that established terminology wasn't used?

Comment: @Alexander `C++` already has a `std::weak_ptr`. It is very much not the same thing though. I can't speak for other languages but `std::weak_ptr` cooperates with reference counted `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 29):

It seems from the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4282.pdf) that `std::observer_ptr` is largely for documenting that a pointer is a *non-owning reference* to an object, rather than an *owning reference*, *array*, *string* or *iterator*.

However there are a couple of other benefits to using `observer_ptr<T>` over `T*`:

1. A default constructed `observer_ptr` will always be initialized to `nullptr`; a regular pointer may or may not be initialized, depending on the context.
2. `observer_ptr` only supports operations which make sense for a *reference*; this enforces correct usage:

   - `operator[]` is not implemented for `observer_ptr`, as this is an *array* operation.
   - Pointer arithmetic is not possible with `observer_ptr`, as these are *iterator* operations.
3. Two `observer_ptr`s have [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) on all implementations, which is not guaranteed for two arbitrary pointers. This is because `operator<` is implemented in terms of [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) for `observer_ptr` (as with [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)).
4. `observer_ptr<void>` appears to be unsupported, which may encourage the use of safer solutions (e.g. [`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) and [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant))

Comment: UVd for the differences; those are some great benefits!

Comment: btw, the version of the proposal you linked is later than that in the accepted answer, and the older one *did* include arithmetic operations, but they were dropped. I get why, but I then wonder why ordering comparisons were kept... they seem like another side of the same coin.

Comment: @underscore_d Late answer, but indeed. You do need to at least implement `std::less` or `operator<` to support use with `std::set` and such, and I suppose if you have `==` and `<` then arguably all of the rest of the operations follow. I would probably argue that it is only necessary to implement `std::less`.

Answer (score 24):

#### Is it just for source self-documentation?

Yes.

Comment: It's not. If it were, `template<typename T> using observer_ptr = T*;` would have done the trick, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Bolpat: It *would* have "done the trick" though. They just added a lot of bells and whistles because they had the opportunity to add some marginal value now that they were adding a new type, which also encourages people to use it. The reason for having it in the first place was just self documentation.

Answer (score 7):

One nice consequence of using `std::observer_ptr` over raw pointers is that it provides a better alternative to the confusing and error prone multiple pointer instantiation syntax inherited from C.

```
std::observer_ptr<int> a, b, c;
```

is an improvement on

```
int *a, *b, *c;
```

which is slightly strange from a C++ perspective and can easily be mistyped as

```
int* a, b, c;
```

Comment: Very true, I've always hated having to write `*` many times; but I also hate useless `typedef`s like `using intp = int*`

Comment: Keep in mind you could already do `std::iterator_traits<T *>::pointer` which is admittedly longer but not by all that much (35 chars instead of 21) considering how both are so much longer than `T *`.

Comment: @Mehrdad: `std::add_pointer_t<T>` seems more appropriate (and it is not longer than    `observer_ptr`).

Comment: @Jarod42 : I was going for a <= C++98 solution, since the problem has always been there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the point of `std::observer_ptr` is largely just "self-documentation" and that is a valid end in and of itself. But it should be pointed out that arguably it doesn't do a great job of that as it's not obvious exactly what an "observer" pointer is. First, as Galik points out, to some the name seems to imply a commitment not to modify the target, which is not the intent, so a name like `access_ptr` would be better. And second, without any qualifiers the name would imply an endorsement of it's "non-functional" behavior. For example, one might consider an `std::weak_ptr` to be a type of "observer" pointer. But `std::weak_ptr` accomodates the case where the pointer outlives the target object by providing a mechanism that allows attempts to access the (deallocated) object to fail safely. `std::observer_ptr`'s implementation does not accomodate this case. So perhaps `raw_access_ptr` would be a better name as it would better indicate its functional shortcoming.

So, as you justifiably ask, what's the point of this functionally challenged "non-owning" pointer? The main reason is probably performance. Many C++ programmers perceive the overhead of an `std::share_ptr` to be too high and so will just use raw pointers when they need "observer" pointers. The proposed `std::observer_ptr` attempts to provide a small improvement of code clarity at an acceptable performance cost. Specifically, zero performance cost.

Unfortunately there seems to be a widespread but, in my opinion, unrealistic optimism about just how safe it is to use raw pointers as "observer" pointers. In particular, while it's easy to state a requirement that the target object must outlive the `std::observer_ptr`, it's not always easy to be absolutely certain it's being satisfied. Consider this example:

```
struct employee_t {
    employee_t(const std::string& first_name, const std::string& last_name) : m_first_name(first_name), m_last_name(last_name) {}
    std::string m_first_name;
    std::string m_last_name;
};

void replace_last_employee_with(const std::observer_ptr<employee_t> p_new_employee, std::list<employee_t>& employee_list) {
    if (1 <= employee_list.size()) {
        employee_list.pop_back();
    }
    employee_list.push_back(*p_new_employee);
}

void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::list<employee_t> current_employee_list;
    current_employee_list.push_back(employee_t("Julie", "Jones"));
    current_employee_list.push_back(employee_t("John", "Smith"));

    std::observer_ptr<employee_t> p_person_who_convinces_boss_to_rehire_him(&(current_employee_list.back()));
    replace_last_employee_with(p_person_who_convinces_boss_to_rehire_him, current_employee_list);
}
```

It may never have occurred to the author of the `replace_last_employee_with()` function that the reference to the new hire could also be a reference to the existing employee to be replaced, in which case the function can inadvertently cause the target of its `std::observer_ptr<employee_t>` parameter to be deallocated before it's finished using it.

It's a contrived example, but this kind of thing can easily happen in more complex situations. Of course using raw pointers is perfectly safe in the vast majority of cases. The problem is that there are a minority of cases where it's easy to assume that it's safe when it really isn't.

If replacing the `std::observer_ptr<employee_t>` parameter with an `std::shared_ptr` or `std::weak_ptr` is for whatever reason not acceptable, there is now another safe option - and this is the shameless plug portion of the answer - "[registered pointers](http://duneroadrunner.github.io/SaferCPlusPlus/#registered-pointers)". "registered pointers" are smart pointers that behave just like raw pointers, except that they are (automatically) set to `null_ptr` when the target object is destroyed, and by default, will throw an exception if you try to access an object that has already been deleted. They are generally [faster](http://duneroadrunner.github.io/SaferCPlusPlus/#simple-benchmarks) than std::shared_ptrs, but if your performance demands are really strict, registered pointers can be "disabled" (automatically replaced with their raw pointer counterpart) with a compile-time directive, allowing them to be used (and incur overhead) in debug/test/beta modes only.

So if there is going to be an "observer" pointer based on raw pointers, then arguably there should be one based on registered pointers and perhaps as the OP suggested, one based on std::shared_ptr too.

Comment: `observer_ptr` does not provide just "a small improvement of code clarity"; see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35897954/2757035) for the objective benefits to safety and semantics, not just self-documentation. For uses where management is undesired, automatic nulling is not needed, etc., `observer_ptr` would provide a fine way to replace raw pointers with something that documents the code & precludes many varieties of foot-shooting, without requiring *any* overhead (in inlineable code; minimal if transferred across APIs), having to include any non-standard classes, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the documentation use case, there are real world issues that can happen when passing around raw pointers without the observer decoration. Other code may incorrectly assume lifetime responsibility for raw pointers and pass the pointer into ownership taking `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, or just plain dispose of the object via `delete`.

This is especially true of legacy code that maybe being upgraded where ownership rules aren't fully established. The `observer_ptr` helps enforce the rule that the lifetime of the object cannot be transferred.

Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct MyObject
{
    int value{ 42 };
};

template<typename T>
void handlerForMyObj(T ptr) noexcept
{
    if (42 != ptr->value) {
        // This object has gone rogue. Dispose of it!
        std::cout << "The value must be 42 but it's actually " << ptr->value << "!\n";
        delete ptr;
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "The value is  " << ptr->value << ".\n";
}

void func1()
{
    MyObject myObj;
    MyObject *myObjPtr = &myObj; 

    myObj.value = 24;

    // What?! Likely run-time crash. BOO!
    handlerForMyObj(myObjPtr);
}

void func2()
{
    MyObject myObj;
    std::observer_ptr<MyObject> myObjObserver{ &myObj };

    myObj.value = 24;

    // Nice! Compiler enforced error because ownership transfer is denied!
    handlerForMyObj(myObjObserver);
}

int main(int argn, char *argv[])
{
    func1();
    func2();
}
```

In the raw pointer case, the incorrect deletion of the object might only be discovered at runtime. But in the `observer_ptr` case, the `delete` operator cannot be applied to the observer.

Comment: "*in the observer_ptr case, the delete operator cannot be applied to the observer.*" Wouldn't the same thing be true of `reference_wrapper`? `delete` doesn't work because `T` is not a raw pointer; the fact that it's specifically `observer_ptr` isn't really relevant. Indeed, you could have passed a `shared_ptr` and achieved the same effect.

Comment: A lot of legacy code passes values by pointer, especially given C++'s C roots. The point of the observer is that you don't know the ownership semantics in the same way that is true of raw pointers (unlike `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`). Yes `reference_wrapper` can be used too but the object would not match existing raw pointer usages as a direct substitute and would be a much wider sweeping change when changing existing code from direct raw pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out various benefits of `observer_ptr` besides self-documenting non-ownership. However, in case you are only interested in conveying non-ownership, Bjarne Stroustrup suggests a succinct alternative for `std::exprimental::observing_ptr` in the [C++ standards working group paper P1408R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1408r0.pdf) (where he, incidentally, proposes to abandon `std::observer_ptr`):

```cpp
template<typename T> using observer_ptr = T*;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need this -- noshared_ptr / noweak_ptr

https://github.com/xhawk18/noshared_ptr